# Is there a way to run unit tests sequentially with MSTests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

I am working in an application that is mostly single-thread, single user.
There are a few worker threads here and there, and they are only using thread safe objects and classes. The unit tests are actually testing those with multiple threads (explicitly created for the tests), and they test fine.

The VSTS unit tests fail when testing business objects and sub-systems that are not thread safe. It is okay for them not to be thread-safe, that's the way the application uses them.

But the 'one thread per TestMethod' approach of MS tests kills us. I've had to implement object locks in many unit test classes just to ensure that the tests are run one after the other (I don't really care about the order, but I can't have two test methods hitting the same object at the same time).

The code looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestSomeObject
{
   static object turnStile = new object();
...
   [TestMethod]
   public void T01_TestThis()
   {
      lock(turnStile)
      {
      .. actual test code
      }
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void T02_TestThat()
   {
      lock(turnStile)
      {
      -- actual test code
      }
   }

}
```

Is there a better/more elegant way to make the test run sequentially?

Comment: so it seems you're reusing an instance of some object in all your tests?

Comment: Yes, essentially. Sometimes it's the database, sometimes it's a singleton - used as it is in the application

Comment: I finally used the ordered test method. It works well. However, I had a hell of a time making it work with the NAnt build.
Running *only* the ordered test list in the build requires using the /testmetadata and /testlist switches in the MSTest invocation block.
The documentation on these is sketchy, to use a kind description. I google all over for examples of "MSTest /testmetadata /testlist" to no effect. The trick is simple, however, and I feel compelled to give it back to the community, in case someone else bumps into the same issue. 1. Edit the test metadata file (with a .vsmdi extension), a

Comment: since you claim this is *unit-testing* by your tag, you should mock/stub out your dependencies, especially dependencies that are not thread safe

Comment: so, the short answer would be: NO. There's no way to do that, because unit tests are not dependable from each other, can you afford to change your tests so that you create and destroy such instance on every test?

Comment: Actually, the answer is yes. I went along with Frank's suggestion and created an ordered test

Comment: (i know this is old) @mxmissile - actually, the dependency could be a function of the test *harness* rather than the tested *unit* -- i.e. if your tests are inheriting from a base test class, and all reusing a deeply nested common variable/method (because it started out easier to reuse the code since all test until "now" behaved the same), then it's easier to be able to adjust that nested variable in your test class than to duplicate 95% of the test just so you can use a different variable.  But changing it for one test run would affect other tests running in parallel...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is the notion of an "Ordered Test" in which you can list tests in sequence. It is more geared towards ensuring a certain sequential order, but I can't see how that would be possible if B doesn't wait for A to complete.

Apart from that, it is unfortunate that your tests interfere with each other. There are Setup / TearDown methods that can be used per test such that it may after all be possible to isolate the tests from each other.

Comment: It's unfortunate that MSTest runs all the tests in the same app domain, making it possible for tests to interfere with one another in the first place.

Answer (score 29):

Use an [**Ordered Test**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630.aspx).

Test > New Test > Ordered Test

[image: Test > New Test]

[image: Ordered Test]

Comment: Great stuff. I knew there HAD to be an easier way... :)

Comment: How do you specify a .runsettings file when using an ordered test?  Specifically, I need to access the TestContext with parameters specified in the .runsettings.

Comment: @ajhuddy: Sounds like a good candidate for a new Stack Overflow question.  Search first to make sure your question hasn't already been asked and answered, and reference this question when writing your new question.

Comment: "MSTest V2 based tests cannot be used in an ordered test" appears at the bottom of the window. Nice.

Answer (score 23):

you can Use **Playlist**

right click on the test method -> Add to playlist -> New playlist

you can then specify the execution order
[image]

Comment: I feel like this is the best answer to the question.

Comment: Worked best, and was easy enough to setup under a minute.

Comment: Is there away to execute the playlist from a the command line in a batch file?

Answer (score 18):

You can specifically require a mutex for each test execution, either in the specific tests you want to serialize, or for all the tests in a class (whatever shares the same mutex string).

For an entire test class, you can use the TestInitialize and TestCleanup attributes like so:

```
private readonly Mutex testMutex = new Mutex(true, "MySpecificTestScenarioUniqueMutexString");

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    testMutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup() {
    testMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

To be clear this isn't a feature of tests, ANY locking structure should work. I'm using the system provided Mutexes in this case:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate? For instance, I need clarification on this "...whatever shares the same mutex string". Also, you declare the testMutex Private ReadOnly but in Initialize and Cleanup you are using FileTestMutex... thx

Comment: Hi there! The reference mismatch was a typo, I've fixed it. I also added a link to the Mutex class for clarification. Mutex is a Microsoft-provided locking structure that uses a systemwide string for locking, so you want the string to be unique per set-of-things-you-want-to-serialize, which could be per test, or for different entire test classes. If you copy/paste the string everywhere, then every use of it will be serialized.
Also note the 'OrderedTest' suggestions above, which is probably a better idea if it works for you. The Mutex (or other manual lock) approach is complicated.

Comment: I wasnt able to use ordered test since i am using MSTest v2. I was trying to use your Mutex approach which seems pretty straightforward but I keep hitting the AbandonedMutex exception, shouldnt the TestCleanup run and release mutex before other threads are able to enter?

Answer (score 9):

I finally used the ordered test method. It works well.

However, I had a hell of a time making it work with the NAnt build.
Running *only* the ordered test list in the build requires using the /testmetadata and /testlist switches in the MSTest invocation block.
The documentation on these is sketchy, to use a kind description. I google all over for examples of "MSTest /testmetadata /testlist" to no effect.

The trick is simple, however, and I feel compelled to give it back to the community, in case someone else bumps into the same issue.

1. Edit the test metadata file (with a .vsmdi extension), and add a new list
   to the list of tests (the first node in the tree on the left
   pane. Give it the name you want, for example  'SequentialTests'.
2. If you used a /testcontainer switch for the MSTest invocation, remove it.
3. Add a switch for MSTest
   -> /testmetadata:
4. Add a switch for MSTEst 
     /testlist:SequentialTests (or whatever name you used)

Then MSTest runs only the tests listed in the test list you created.

If someone has a better method, I'd like to hear about it!

Answer (score 2):

I used ordered tests, also configured them easily on jenkins just use command

MSTest /testcontainer:"orderedtestfilename.orderedtest" /resultsfile:"testresults.trx"