# Single thread for C# unit testing suite

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com, interop

Is there any way to run the C# test in single thread? I am not looking for a thread safe but for a single thread. Actually my COM component can be used in single thread only so when i run my first test it runs fine but as soon as it enters another it fails as COM component cannot be assigned to another thread"

Comment: Which testing framework are you referring to?

Comment: C# unit testing framework?

Comment: Which C# unit testing framework?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, which one? MSTest, NUnit, XUnit, ANOtherUnit? Each will have a different way of dealing with this situation.

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

Answer (score 1):

[MSTest doesn't support single-threaded testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037514/7122). You'll therefore have to use another testing framework. Many options exist, though [NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.6.3) and [XUnit](http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html) would both meet your needs and both are popular.

Answer (score 0):

VSTest.Console.Exe suppose to replace MSTest.  It uses single thread -see [How does the Visual Studio 2012 test runner apply threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860665/how-does-the-visual-studio-2012-test-runner-apply-threading).

If you solution using .runsettings(e.g. see [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) ) Visual Studio will run VSTest.Console.Exe.

More details about MSTest/VStest differences are in [Choose and configure a test runner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138(v=vs.110).aspx#Runner)