# How to force specific Visual Basic .NET unit test to run serially

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, resharper

When configuring tests to run in parallel, such as using ReSharper, there seems to be no way to flag a specific unit test class to be run serially.

An example of a class that requires this could be one that deletes/recreates data before each indiviual test (from a database or just file structures).

If parallel test runs start, they can all hit the MyTestInitialize() at any point, which leads to chaos for other tests that are in the middle of asserting various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A good way in Visual Studio 2010 seems to be to create a class with a single shared object that can then be locked when MyTestIntialize() is called and unlocked when MyTestCleapup() is called.

eg

```
' Prevent resharper running tests in parallel
Public Class SingleProcess
    Public Shared Lock As New Object
End Class
'.....
<TestClass()> _
Public Class MyTestClass

    <TestInitialize()> _
    Public Sub MyTestInitialize()
        Threading.Monitor.Enter(SingleProcess.Lock)
        ' Do initialize stuff
    End Sub
    '
    <TestCleanup()> _
    Public Sub MyTestCleanup()
        ' Release lock
        Threading.Monitor.Exit(SingleProcess.Lock)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Visual Studio's `Ordered Tests` feature to define the sequence in which your unit tests need to run.

However, remember that each unit test should be isolated and should not depend on the results of the previous unit test.

References:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544827/is-there-a-way-to-run-unit-tests-sequentially-with-mstests) SO thread
- [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms182631.aspx) MSDN article

Comment: they are depending on the Initialization section, thats what it is there for. What happens however is multiple threads are running the tests and hit the init section a different times, and since they are dealing with a single real object, in this case datafiles in a directory, all hell breaks loose.

Comment: The tests are also no depending on the results of the previous unit tests at all, they are dependent on accessing a global resource, in this case a file. It is perfectly fine to have a class of unit tests without dependencies that use mock objects to verify interactions AND have another set of tests that actually test the integration and real interactions with objects such as databases and files.