# Selenium Webdriver C# Framework Supporting Ordered Test Runs

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mstest

**Update** *Almost 3 years later I've come back to update this post with a link to the NUnit documentation on how to do ordered tests using that framework: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute*

I am new to selenium webdriver (and development!) and am taking over maintaining tests/framework written in C# (MSTEST) by an engineer who has now left the business.

Because our app is quite complicated there are pre-requisite 'setup' steps to tests, so they must run in a particular order. To achieve this, the following repeated code is included in every 'step':

```
        //Check the previous step ran
        if( m_MethodFlag != "_05_PreviousStep" )
        {
            _05_PreviousStep();
        }
```

This is obviously difficult to maintain and to my limited dev experience seems really inefficient and unreliable.

My question - does anyone know of a way of achieving ordered test runs (through CI/Nightly deployment) without adding complexity like the code above? We use VS 2015. I am open to using a completely new framework as long as it supports C#. Many thanks in advance!

Edit* To clarify, the code is saying - check that the previous test (step) ran and if not then go and run it. The trouble is that this bit of code is required at every single 'step' and each has a unique name so when changing around steps its a nightmare to maintain.

Edit2* Maybe it will help to post an entire step:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is an example TestMethod, there are probably 20+ of these in each test
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void _008_CurrentStepName()
    {
        //Check if the set up method had ran
        if( m_MethodFlag != "_007_ThePreviousTestName" )
        {
            _007_ThePreviousTestName();
        }
        Thread.Sleep( LONG_WAIT );

        // Do something
        m_DriverHelpers...

        //Set the method flag
        m_MethodFlag = GetCurrentMethod();
    }
```

As you can see, the bulk of each 'step' within the test is just the code that is trying to order it.

Comment: Just run them in order and stop when one fails? I don't get it

Comment: To clarify, it means check that the previous test (step) ran and if not then go and run it. The trouble is that this bit of code is required at every single 'step' and each has a unique name.

Comment: Why is it required to check if something ran, there should be red flags popping everywhere if a test doesn't run.

Comment: Hi Kip, I've included some more code in the original post which should hopefully help. Its difficult to describe but there are multiple test methods within each 'test' that essential make up the execution 'steps' and these need to run in a specific order which is where my problem is because it takes so much code to try and ensure they run in the correct order.

Comment: The code does not make sense, if I just run them in order it will never be that the previous hasn't run yet. And if there tend to be people testing just 1 test, just make 1 'master test' that contains calls to the tests IN ORDER

Comment: That's specifically my problem, my understanding is that using the VS MSTEST framework will execute the tests in random (like unit tests) but I need them to execute in a particular order. Also, if I combine all the 'steps' into a single test its difficult to get any kind of reporting as to why the test failed. Again, sorry if I am not making complete sense or struggling to understand but this topic is still very new to me. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I don't have much experience with unit tests either, I used selenium for a while but just made my own framework with custom error reporting. First idea that pops up is make 1 master, make the test return a bool (true/false) and you can log if they succeeded from the master method. Then save that somehow

Comment: I would answer but I don't know the specifics of this so I'd just be guessing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29039198/3110529 This answer may be of use to you, some of the other answers may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Dilan. I think that will do what I'm looking for!